# Get response as a file inside the S3 bucket folder, when hit the url till folder

Tags: amazon-s3

I have file in the S3 bucket in folder under S3 bucket.

My requirement is that I want to get response as file when I hit the file URL till folder instead of full address including filename under the folder.

Example: www.example.com/folder/filename.json (In this case I will get response as filename.json). But my requirement is to get response as filename.json when I will hit only www.example.com/folder.

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Just save the object with a key matching what you want to hit.  If you want to hit `www.example.com/folder` and get some json, just save the json as that name: `folder`.  Extensions have no meaning on the Internet, it's the `Content-Type` (e.g. `application/json`) that matters.  It's not clear what your motivation is.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written so far, and the problem you're experiencing?